# Can I export the shared Google Calendar to another format after subscription

Tags: google-calendar, export

I am trying to find the dates all public holiday for the year 2012, for several countries. There are many public holiday calendars for different countries shared at the Google Calendar (see [here](https://www.google.com/calendar/render?gsessionid=OK)).

After I subscribed these calenders, can I export these subscribed calenders to another format such as CSV, Excel or text format?

Answer (score 2):

You can import it as an XML into Microsoft Excel. To do so:

- Go to your calendar setting.
- Click on the calendar in question; the calendar settings will show up.
- On the right hand side click on XML. Google Calendar will provide you with a link.
- Open Excel and click on open file.
- Copy and paste the provided link into the **File Name** field and click open.
- Follow the instructions given by Microsoft Excel.

Now you will have to format it in a usable way.